# accessing shape attribute for points when making NVD3 scatterChart with nplot/rCharts

Tags: r, nvd3.js, rcharts

How do you set the shape attribute for points when building a scatterChart with nplot from rCharts? Point size can be set by providing a column in the input dataframe named "size" but if there's a corresponding "shape" column consisting of strings such as "square" or "cross" the resulting graph still has the default circle points. New to R and NVD3 so I apologize for my lack of vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the newest version of nvd3 no longer works the same way as the old version.  See for [example](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/scatter.html).  The [screenshot](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/examples.html) shows shapes, and the data has `shape:`, but only circles are rendered in the actual chart.  Also, the [tests](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/tree/master/test) do not produce anything other than circles.  I glanced at the source, and I could not find where or how to set shape.  If you know how to do with nvd3, I could easily translate into a rCharts example.

Comment: I have seen an argument hidden deep in NVD3 called `onlyCircles` which is set to be TRUE by default. So doing something like `n1$chart(onlyCircles = FALSE)` should allow shapes to be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a reputation of 50, but I'd like to comment.

Line 18 in [this NVD3 example](http://novus.github.io/nvd3/ghpages/scatter.html)(Novus.github) shows how it's currently done. Likewise, all you need to do with the [live code](http://nvd3.org/livecode/#codemirrorNav)(nvd3.org) is uncomment the 'size' line in the data tab.

I attempted making a column in my df named 'shape', and using `n1 <- nPlot(x~y, data=df, shape='shape', type='scatterChart'); n1$chart(onlyCircles=FALSE);` and a number of other combinations. I've only spent the last two days working with rCharts but have made some exciting progress. I'm giving up on this but found it curious that these two examples weren't mentioned here, so I thought I'd mention them.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit "ancient" but I faced the same problem and it took me a while to find out how to change the shapes.

I followed the approach in this example for changing the size:
[nvd3 scatterPlot with rCharts in R: Vary size of points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421211/nvd3-scatterplot-with-rcharts-in-r-vary-size-of-points)

Here my solution:

```
library(rCharts)
df=data.frame(x=rep(0:2,3),y=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3)),
group=c(rep("a",3),rep("b",3),rep("c",3)),shape=rep("square",9))

p <- nPlot(y~x , group = 'group',data = df, type = 'scatterChart')

#In order to make it more pleasant to look at
p$chart(xDomain=c(-0.5,2.5))
p$chart(yDomain=c(0,4))
p$chart(sizeRange = c(200,200))

#here the magic
p$chart(scatter.onlyCircles = FALSE)
p$chart(shape = '#! function(d){return d.shape} !#')

p
```