# Increase point size of all points for rCharts NVD3

Tags: r, nvd3.js, rcharts

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421211/nvd3-scatterplot-with-rcharts-in-r-vary-size-of-points) question, it is possible to vary the size of points based on a variable in your dataset.  Is it possible to simply increase the size of all points to make them more visible?

```
library(rCharts)
p2 <- nPlot(mpg ~ wt, group = 'cyl', data = mtcars, type = 'scatterChart')
p2$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Weight')
p2$chart(size = '1000') #Also tried 1000, '1000px', etc.
p2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using this very helpful answer [d3.v3 scatterplot with all circles the same radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909793/d3-v3-scatterplot-with-all-circles-the-same-radius/20914196#20914196)

```
library(rCharts)
p2 <- nPlot(mpg ~ wt, group = 'cyl', data = mtcars, type = 'scatterChart')
p2$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Weight')
#p2$chart(size = 100) #Also tried 1000, '1000px', etc.
p2$chart(sizeRange = c(1000,1000))
p2
```